# node request could not wait until response, even using callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, httprequest

Here is the code I am testing, it does not return response every time. Like I run it 20 times, there is only one time I could get output of the body. Other times, I got nothing output, even not seeing any error messages.

I guess it is because the request runs too fast to get response back.

Could  anyone help me with this?
Thanks.

```
get_from_google : function (callback) {
    request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
            console.info('Success');
            callback(body);
            //console.log(body); // Show the HTML for the Google homepage.
        } else {
            console.info('Failed');
            //console.log(body)
        }
        console.info('google request')
    }).on('body',function (body) {
        callback(body);
    })
}
```

I added output within the function(err,response,body), like below. But nothing got output.

```
get_from_google : function (callback) {
    request('http://www.google.com', function(err, res, body) {
        console.info('In the callback');
        if (err)
            return callback(err);
        if (res.statusCode === 200) {
            callback(new Error('Nothing got back'), body);
        } else {
            callback(new Error('Unexpected status code: ' + res.statusCode));
        }
    });
}
```

Here is the output in the console:

```
Starting selenium standalone server...
[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver
Selenium standalone server started at http://10.33.203.210:53537/wd/hub
Started
.


Ran 1 of 3 specs
1 spec, 0 failures
Finished in 0.019 seconds
Shutting down selenium standalone server.
[launcher] 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[launcher] chrome #01 passed

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Well, uhm, you are not calling the callback in the else statement (I don't understand why you are listening for `body`). What is `request` - the request module or what?

Comment: Yes i am using npm reqeust moduel.
The issue I have here is nothing got call back.The code within function(error, response, body) does not get executed.

Comment: Can you show exactly how you are testing this particular function? Perhaps you are not waiting for the function to complete before marking the test as finished?

Comment: The solution is to use promise.controlfolw.wait to wait for the promise.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few issues here:

1. Request errors are being ignored. An error can occur if there is a problem connecting to the server for example.
2. Adding a `body` event handler is unnecessary since you already have the other callback.
3. It's best to keep with the node-style callback signature of `(err, result[, ...resultn])`.

With these things in mind, you might try something like:

```
get_from_google: function(callback) {
  request('http://www.google.com', function(err, res, body) {
    if (err)
      return callback(err);
    if (res.statusCode === 200) {
      callback(null, body);
    } else {
      callback(new Error('Unexpected status code: ' + res.statusCode));
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: I have tried it
But I still could not get response back every time.
The test Finished in 0.019 seconds.
Is it too fast to finish the request?
Because I am trying to output body within the function(err, res, body). However, I got nothing output.